# Be $f:\;(a,b)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ a continuous function. Suppose $c\in(a,b)$ ...

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives, real-numbers

I got a problem with this theorem:

Theorem: Let $f:\;(a,b)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Suppose $c\in(a,b)$ is such that f is differentiable in $(a,c)$and in $(c,b)$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow c}f'(x)=L$. Prove $f$ is differentiable in $c$ and $f'(c)=L$

Proof:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow c}\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}=\lim_{x\rightarrow c}\frac{f(c)-f(x)}{c-x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow c}f'(x)=L$$ Then $f'(c)$ exists and $f'(c)=L$

Is my proof fine?

Comment: Is fine my prove?

Comment: No, your second to last equality of limits is not trivially true. At that point you do not even know yet whether the limit of the difference quotient exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will prove $\lim\limits_{t \to c^+} \frac{f(t)-f(c)}{t-c}=L$ and leave the left-handed limit case for you.

Take $\epsilon>0$. Now, consider $\delta>0$ such that $x-c<\delta \implies |f'(x)-L| < \epsilon.$

Now, if $x-c<\delta$, we have that $|\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}-L|=|f'(\xi)-L|<\epsilon,$ where the equality is given for some $\xi$ between $c$ and $x$ by the mean value theorem, and the inequality by the way we defined $\delta$. It follows that $\lim\limits_{t \to c^+} \frac{f(t)-f(c)}{t-c}=L$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hints**:

- For $x$ sufficiently close to $c$ we have $f'(x)$ bounded in an interval based on $L\pm\varepsilon$.
- This implies that $f(c)$ must be found between the lines with slopes $L-\varepsilon$ and $L+\varepsilon$ through $(x,f(x))$ for $x$ sufficiently close to $c$. Here the continuity of $f$ should play a role.
- Since this can be achieved for all $\varepsilon>0$ the conclusion should follow.

Perhaps someone else will provide a completely different approach, but this was my intuition regarding this problem.

Comment: @Bvss12: No problem, but I think the way Alozio Macedo has answered it is more of a standard approach, since some way of applying the mean value theorem will be the way to proceed.